# unset a flag from within a python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a large collection of regular expressions, and I apply them all using a few flags with something like:

```
re.search(aRegex,aString,flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
```

unfortunately, there are one or two for which I don't want to ignore case. Python provides a handy way to set flags from within a regular expression (eg: `r'(?iu)...'` sets the `re.IGNORECASE` and `re.UNICODE` flags).

Is there a way that I can **unset** flags from within an expression? Perhaps somerthing like:

```
r'(?i-)...'
```

or

```
r'(?I)...'
```

to force case sensitivity. (btw: neither of those work..)

Comment: hold on, do you have to modify the regex? Or can we modify the flags? (Edit: I see the question says from within the expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to unset a flag once you set it (in the regex or in a function) in the Python 2.x `re` module. (There is also no way to set a flag for a portion of the regex either).

Consider using [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package if you need such feature.

Comment: Apparently `regex` may be added to Python 3.4

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 3.6 you can use `(?-i:YOUR_REGEX_HERE)` to unset the `i` (ignore case) flag for part of a regular expression ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/re.html#index-16)).